# How to know what is the name in my chosen row in db?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I create a login form in c# and I write the code to know whether the username and password is correct or not, and i succeeded.

But now I want to say hello to the person that's logging in.

My Database: Mysql and I use linq for that.

This is my code for the login button:

```
var query = from r in db.Users
            where r.Username.ToString() == txtusername.Text && r.Password == txtpassword.Text
            select r;

if (query.Count() == 1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Welcom");
}
else
{
   MessageBox.Show("Wrong Username Or password!!!");
}
```

This code is working, but I don't know to how to change my message box to this :

```
MessageBox.Show("Welcom" + Firstname);
```

```
My database table's columns:
    Rownumber
    Firstname
    Lasttname
    Username
    Password
```

Comment: `query.First().Firstname`

Comment: Just so it's said...if you can compare passwords against a text field like that, you're not storing them properly.  Passwords shouldn't be in plain text, ever.

Comment: THANKS but i just start to learn linq in c# and its not a program i just want to learn but that security issue is important and thanks to remembering to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below line you

```
MessageBox.Show("Welcom "+query.FirstOrDefault().Firstname);
```

Comment: This should have a null check: `MessageBox.Show("Welcom "+query.FirstOrDefault()?.Firstname ?? string.Empty);`

Comment: @Stefan not required he is already checking count in if statement

Comment: Then why use `FirstOrDefault()`? This is contradictory. If you use `FirstOrDefault()` you take into account that there might be a situation where you receive null. If you are absolutely certain that it will never happen, than just use `First()`. Also, to be more exact, include the if statement that checks the count in your answer, just to be clear.

Answer (score 0):

Check below code

```
if (query.Count() > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Welcome " + query.FirstOrDefault().Firstname);
}
```